# element is taking attribute values from another element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, padding

I wrote some code that has two canvases positioned in the center of the screen, and I have functions that change the padding when the window loads and when it is resized so it can always be centered. I put them in a div with an ID so i could use .getElementById().setAttribute() and change the left and top padding when the window is resized. This all works fine until i try to add other elements to the page. Anything I put afterwards also has the padding applied to it (but only on the top, i can set my own padding-left) even if they are in their own div with their own id, so I'm wondering if there is something in my javascript code that is altering these elements. Here is my html code:

```
<html>
<head><title>cyclops</title></head>
<body>
<div id="padding" style="">
    <div style="position:absolute;">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="z-index:2;position:absolute;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="layer2" width="400" height="400" style="z-index:3;position:absolute;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="separate"> 
<img src="putput2.png" height="100" width="100" style="padding-left:100;padding-top:100">
/* adding or removing the "padding-top" part doesnt change anything ^^^^^ */
</div>
<script src="cyclops.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript that is relevant:

```
//globals
    var canvasPadding = document.getElementById('padding')
    var currentHeight = 0; //innerwidth
    var currentWidth = 0; //innerheight
    var center_x = 0; //center x of the innerWidth
    var center_y = 0; //centery of the innerHeight
    var mousex = 0;
    var mousey = 0;
    var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var c2 = document.getElementById('layer2');
    var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
window.onload=function(load){
    currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var initialPadding = currentHeight / 2 - 200;
    var initialPadding2 = currentWidth / 2 - 200;
    canvasPadding.setAttribute("style","padding-top:" + initialPadding + ";padding-left:" + initialPadding2);
    center_x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    center_y = window.innerHeight / 2;
    draw_eye(ctx);
    draw_nose(ctx);
    draw_head(ctx);
}
window.addEventListener('resize', e=> {
    currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var newPadding = currentHeight / 2 - 200;
    var newPadding2 = currentWidth / 2 - 200;
    canvasPadding.setAttribute("style","padding-top:" + newPadding + ";padding-left:" + newPadding2);
    center_x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    center_y = window.innerHeight / 2;
})
```

Comment: `padding` is inside an element, maybe you need `margin`, which defines distances between elements.

Comment: using margin instead of padding doesnt change anything unfortunately

Comment: Padding/margin needs an unit, you've set plain numbers as values.

Comment: that doesn't change anything either. Using inspect element i see that there is a padding element on top of the body element, so the body is offset. What I was trying to do was put in images or text within that padding; basically i wanted to have the canvases floating in the center and still be able to put stuff around it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add px or some other unit while you adding padding or margin

Like this

```
canvasPadding.setAttribute("style","padding-top:" + newPadding + ";padding-left:" + newPadding2+"px");

//globals
    var canvasPadding = document.getElementById('padding')
    var currentHeight = 0; //innerwidth
    var currentWidth = 0; //innerheight
    var center_x = 0; //center x of the innerWidth
    var center_y = 0; //centery of the innerHeight
    var mousex = 0;
    var mousey = 0;
    var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var c2 = document.getElementById('layer2');
    var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
window.onload=function(load){
    currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var initialPadding = currentHeight / 2 - 200;
    var initialPadding2 = currentWidth / 2 - 200;
    canvasPadding.setAttribute("style","padding-top:" + initialPadding + ";padding-left:" + initialPadding2+"px");
    center_x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    center_y = window.innerHeight / 2;
    draw_eye(ctx);
    draw_nose(ctx);
    draw_head(ctx);
}
window.addEventListener('resize', e=> {
    currentHeight = window.innerHeight;
    currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var newPadding = currentHeight / 2 - 200;
    var newPadding2 = currentWidth / 2 - 200;
    canvasPadding.setAttribute("style","padding-top:" + newPadding + ";padding-left:" + newPadding2+"px");
    center_x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    center_y = window.innerHeight / 2;
})
```